# Join two columns of dictionaries in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a dataframe with two columns. Each column has a dictionnary, as such:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[{'a': 'one', 'b': 'two'}, {'c': 'three', 'd': 'four'}],
                   [{'a': 'five', 'b': 'six'}, {'c': 'seven', 'd': 'eight'}]],
                  columns=list('AB'))
```

Which gives:

```
                           A                             B
0   {'a': 'one', 'b': 'two'}   {'c': 'three', 'd': 'four'}
1  {'a': 'five', 'b': 'six'}  {'c': 'seven', 'd': 'eight'}
```

Considering that in my data some entries might be empty, I would like to join the two columns' dictionnaries, so that the final output looks like this:

```
                  A               
0  {'a': 'one', 'b': 'two', 'c': 'three', 'd': 'four'}
1  {'a': 'five', 'b': 'six', 'c': 'seven', 'd': 'eight'}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one approach using [dictionary unpacking](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/operators/dict_unpack.html):

```
pd.Series(({**a,**b} for a,b in  df.to_numpy().tolist()), name='A')
0    {'a': 'one', 'b': 'two', 'c': 'three', 'd': 'f...
1    {'a': 'five', 'b': 'six', 'c': 'seven', 'd': '...
Name: A, dtype: object
```

Or with `ChainMap`:

```
from collections import ChainMap
pd.Series((dict(ChainMap(*i)) for i in df.to_numpy().tolist()), name='A')
0    {'c': 'three', 'd': 'four', 'a': 'one', 'b': '...
1    {'c': 'seven', 'd': 'eight', 'a': 'five', 'b':...
Name: A, dtype: object
```

Comment: The first one already works for me thank you very much ! For anyone having a dataframe with more than two columns, you only have to specify which columns you want to join using: ```df[['a', 'b']].to_numpy().tolist())```

Answer (score 0):

With looping you can do it in this way:

```
for i in range(len(df)):
    df.A.iloc[i].update(df.B.iloc[i])
result=df.A
```

Maybe there is some more pythonic way though

Answer (score 0):

Is there a good reason to avoid using the dictionary keys as columns? That would align better with the intended use of dataframes.

```
>>> for letter in ("a", "b"):
        df[letter] = [i[letter] for i in df.A]

>>> for letter in ("c", "d"):
        df[letter] = [i[letter] for i in df.B]

>>> df = df.drop(["A", "B"], axis=1)

>>> df
      a    b      c      d
0   one  two  three   four
1  five  six  seven  eight
```